# Missing word! What word am I looking for?

Tags: cipher

What word am I looking for? Try decipher the following:

**((CZ18172612)⁺¹**)=_____?

Edit; Gary S was very close, but here's a hint...

> If numbers equals letters, then...

Comment: Is the word in any particular language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It Is:

> 14 Mars or Mars 14

Because:

> CZ = 4(26) + 1 = 41
>  And as per the explanation above, 18172612 = SRAM
>  Therefore, we got: 41 SRAM
>  After reversing it, we get Mars 14, or 14 Mars

As a conclusion:

> I believe the word is "Pi", as March 14th is the National Pi Day

Comment: I've added spoiler markdown to your answer.

Comment: Yes you're correct, its Mars 14. And whats the word im looking for, you think?

Comment: Maybe rot13(Creuncf lbh ner gnyxvat nobhg gur Ntvyrag Uhzna 14 Zhygvcyr Nssvavgl Erzbiny
Flfgrz NXN 14 Znef, fb gur jbeq lbh ner ybbxvat sbe vf Ntvyrag be cebgrva?)

Comment: I've added my guess for the word too!

Comment: problem solved :)

Answer (score 7):

Here's a guess:

> DASRAM

Rationale:

> It's not a common English word, but [Google says it's a word](https://www.google.com/search?q=dasram), so I thought I would try it. I got this answer by applying the `⁺¹` to 1) each letter (i.e. C + 1 = D) and 2) each two-digit number as if it were a letter (i.e. 18 + 1 = 19 = S, 26 + 1 = 27 -> wraparound to 1 -> A).
>
>  D = C + 1
>  A = Z + 1 (wraparound)
>  S = (18 = R) + 1
>  R = (17 = Q) + 1
>  A = (26 = Z) + 1 (wraparound)
>  M = (12 = L) + 1

Comment: You're very very close... You just have to re-think what the meaning of the two letters in the beginning are..

Comment: if rot13(Gur yrggref trg pbairegrq onpx gb ahzoref) 
then rot13( 427 FENZ ybbxf yvxr vg zvtug or n zbqry bs zbhagnva ovxr ) ... maybe?